# How to attach debugger for Deep Link Android App trigger debug launch?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-deep-link

As per posted in https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html, we could start the deeplink App Launch using the below command

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://gizmos" com.example.android
```

But if I want to start debugging, I could add a `-D`, as below

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://gizmos" com.example.android -D
```

My App got launched, but it is there stating

```
Waiting For Debugger
Application Android System (process system:ui) is waiting for the debugger to attach
```

From there, I check my Android Studio, it is not attached. Wonder how could I get it attached?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd either have to manually attach it after launching, or already have the app running and attached then launch your deeplink.  There's no way for the phone to know it needs to attach to a debugger on a connected PC when it launches an app.

Comment: How to 'manually attach'? Is it from the Android Studio, or command line we could do so?

Comment: Generally Android studio if you plan on using it as a graphical debugger. Under the build menu there's an option "Attach debugger to Android process"

Answer (score 43):

there is a great [article](https://medium.com/@elye.project/debug-app-deeplink-at-launch-time-bdb2cf04a9e6) and a great comment under it.

Briefly:
1. Before the line you want to debug put `Debug.waitForDebugger()`.
2. Put breakpoint where you need it.
3. Run application (from deeplink, in this case).
4. You will see it's frozen.
5. In Android Studio attach debugger to process.
6. Voila! Now you have debugger activated on that breakpoint.

In this way I was able to debug deeplinks.

Comment: Great. Works directly in Android Studio (4.0.1), no need for command-line tools